# Has anyone effectively integrated GD star rating and Cube Points?

Tags: plugin-gd-star-rating

Has anyone effectively integrated [GD star rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/) and [Cube Points](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cubepoints/)?

From the documentation:

> Plugin Integration CubePoints can also
>   be easily integrated with other
>   plugins. Other plugins can be coded
>   such that certain actions trigger the
>   cp_alterPoints() function to add or
>   subtract points from a specified user.

**Function**

```
cp_alterPoints( int $uid, int $points )
```

**Parameters**

> int $uid: ID of a Wordpress user. To
>   get the ID of the current logged in
>   user, use the cp_currentUser()
>   function.
>
> int $return: Number of points to add
>   to the specified user.

Example

The following code will add 10 points to the current logged in user. If no user is logged in, no points will be added. You may input negative number to subtract points.

```
<php
  if( function_exists('cp_alterPoints') && is_user_logged_in() ){
    cp_alterPoints(cp_currentUser(), 10);
    cp_log('hey', cp_currentUser(), 10, 1);
  }
?>
```

In this case, I would like to add 10 points to the user, if his or her post is voted (GD star rating's thumbs rating system).

But I have no idea how to do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this page](http://whyy.org/cms/wp-content/plugins/gd-star-rating/info/filters.html), you can see that `gdsr_vote_rating_article` is the hook you need - it gets called when a post rating is saved.

Comment: Sorry I have little knowledge about php, how that would look like in the function?

Answer (score 2):

After some googling, and trial and error, here is the solution:

```
add_action( 'gdsr_vote_thumb_article', 'cubepoints_vote_up_down', 10, 4 );        
function cubepoints_vote_up_down() {
    global $bp;
    cp_points( 'star_rating', cp_currentUser(), 1, $data );
}

add_action( 'cp_logs_description', 'cp_admin_logs_desc_star_rating', 10, 4 );
function cp_admin_logs_desc_star_rating( $type, $uid, $points, $data ) {
    global $bp;
    if ( $type != 'star_rating' ) { return; }
    $post = get_post( $data );
    echo 'Voted for ' . $post;
}
```

This is for the `gdsr_vote_thumb_article` hook (thumb up/down), but if you want to attach the rating hook, use `gdsr_vote_rating_article`.

This will give a user who rated 1 point, regardless if he voted up or down.

If you want to pass the value of the actual rating, you need to `$_GET` some params from `gd-star-rating` AJAX call:

```
function cubepoints_vote_up_down() {
    global $bp;
    // get voted post id
    $post_id = $_GET['vote_id'];
    // get the value of rating
    $vote = $_GET['vote_value'];

    if ( $vote == 'up' ) {
        $point = '1';
    } else {
        $point = '-1';
    }
}
```

If you want to give points to the author of the post, instead of the current logged in user:

```
function cubepoints_vote_up_down() {
    global $bp, $wpdb, $post;
    $post_id = $_GET['vote_id'];
    $vote = $_GET['vote_value'];

    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    $post_author = $post->post_author;

    if ( $vote == 'up' ) {
        $point = '1';
    } else {
        $point = '-1';
    }
    cp_points( 'thumb_up_down', $post_author, $point, $data );
}
```